# Nokia Lumia 820 (Windows Phone): Can't vote on comments on full site

Tags: support, mobile-web, windows-phone

Well, I have a Nokia Lumia 820 and can't vote on comments in the full site (no arrow is displayed). Is there a workaround for this?

*EDIT*

Tap&hold works in the neighbourhood of arrow to show it. However, I still can't click the arrow, it disappears too quickly.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. While you're doing that, I'll test on my Lumia....

Comment: Tap in the neighborhood of where the arrow should be, that should show the outline, then tap on the upvote arrow.

Comment: I can't even log in on my Lumia, having SSL issues :/

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186622/close-dialog-does-nothing-on-ios

Comment: Kevin, I tried to upvote your comment the way you suggested but nothing shows when I click the neighbourhood. I tried several times.